# how to select column name which contains not null value for particular input in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, procedure

i want to select only those column which contains not null values in oracle

```
emp_id   name     sal     age     hire_date 
1        alex     5000    null     null
2        andy     null    24       null
```

for e.g, if i give input as emp_id=1, i should get output as emp_id, name, sal only

if i give input as emp_id=2, it should return emp_id, name, age only.

i want to write query in oracle for this scenario.

Comment: Will you input only by emp_id? Which I have to assume it's unique

Comment: yes, emp_id will be unique.

Comment: well you can't do that in just SQL as far as i know. How would you like to handle it in PL/SQL?

Comment: yeah, can you pls help me, how to write logic for this using pl//sql?

Comment: You can't do this with a SQL statement, because a `SELECT` statement has a fixed number of columns.  In PL/SQL, you can query the table, return a row, and then print the values that are not `NULL`.

Comment: can you help using plsql with a example,
if there are 50 columns how to check columns are not null dynamically?

Answer (score -3):

What the code will look like -- this is PL/SQL:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the above query, i have one doubt, whether we can select all those column where values is not  null for a given input, instead of printing that value?